# Ansible Local Python Script with Parameters

Tags: python, automation, ansible

So here is what I want to do I want to run a playbook like this

```
ansible-playbook playbookX.yml --ask-vault-pass [host or hostgroup]
```

The playbook should run a local (on the ansible server) python script with parameters

```
python scriptname.py Parameter1 Parameter2
```

`Parameter1`: a secret that should be encrypted and not visible i.e. with ps -aufx and I should get the password from a vault-file. Maybe I should decrypt it in the python script?

`Parameter2`: The hostname specified in host or hostgroup
(Note: The script should be run for every host when the playbook is run with a hostgroup)

Another note: The python script should best be executed in a virtual_env while the environment should have urllib3 installed.

How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify urllib3 is present in the venv with the pip module:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/pip_module.html

I think you need to pass the host/hostgroup as a var on command line to the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook playbookX.yml -e "myhosts=[host or hostgroup]" --ask-vault-pass
```

I suggest use no_log on the task to hide the parameters in the output. I guess it will still show in with ps though.

```
---
- name: Run on remote host
  hosts: "{{ myhosts }}"

  tasks:
    - <my other tasks on remote host>
    - name: run python script locally
      local_action: command python scriptname.py "{{ my_ecrypted_password }}" "{{ myhosts }}"
      no_log: True
```

You could create a template scriptname.py.j2, add "{{ my_encrypted_password }}" where needed, then create your tmp scriptname.py, execute and remove the tmp file. That was it won't show with ps but it will be in the tmp .py file.

Last suggestions would be to just put it in the .py scipt and encrypt it with ansible-vault.

Comment: If I take your last suggestion and put it in the py-script then encrypt it with ansible vault. How would I call it in a playbook?

Comment: Starting to play with this, I realized it is it not such a good idea. Another way would be to put your script in a role, the password in the role vars and encrypt it. Check this out: [https://gist.github.com/tristanfisher/e5a306144a637dc739e7](https://gist.github.com/tristanfisher/e5a306144a637dc739e7)

Comment: In the end I solved this using just ansible modules, an inline-vault and no external python-script. But thanks for your help. I have to definitly learn about roles.

Comment: I am glad you did, can you post your solution in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a virtual environment :

- virtualenv env_name
- source dir/bin/activate

I'm assuming you want to do something like this:

python some_script.py param1 param2

To pass and fetch parameters to a Python Script you need to use sys.

```
import sys
param1 = sys.argv[1]
param2 = sys.argv[2]
```

Use getpass() in python to accept passwords in the command line.

Comment: Sorry, but I know how to create a virtualenv for python. The question was how to do it in combination with ansible as a playbook which your answer completely omits. Thus -1